# Reading tab delimited ints into a struct in C

Tags: c, file, input, file-io, struct

I'm trying to read a file that looks like the following:

```
PID Start   Duration    Size    Priority    Threads
0   0   400 440 1   1
1   20  250 560 2   1
2   50  80  810 1   2
3   80  120 220 1   1
4   125 560 460 2   4
5   140 40  850 4   8
```

Basically, it represents a bunch of processes that an OS will use.  To store all of these, I've created a struct of a process:

```
struct process{
    int pid;
    int start;
    int duration;
    int size;
    int priority;
    int threads;
};
```

I've read the number of lines in the file and subtracted one to get the number of processes that I'll need to store.  I then created an array as follows:

```
struct process allProcesses[numProcesses];
```

Now, my issue is: how do I read these tab delimited ints into structs, where each line is its own struct? In pseudocode, this would be:

```
for (i = -1; i < numProcesses; ++i){
    if (i == -1){
        skip first line, continue;
    }
    struct process tempProcess = {firstInt, secondInt, thirdInt, fourthInt, fifthInt, sixthInt}, where each int is tab-delimited 
    allProcesses[i] = tempProcess
}
```

I'm considering using fgets(), but was wondering if there is a simpler way.  Thanks!

Comment: `fgets()` and `strtok()` will do the trick.

Comment: Standard C's [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) or POSIX's
[`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) in combination with Standard C's 
[`sscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sscanf.html) will do the trick.  You lose control over line breaks if you use `scanf()` or `fscanf()` directly.

Comment: If you use [`strtok()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtok.html), you have to convert the strings it isolates into integers, using [`atoi()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/atoi.html)
 if you don't care about errors and [`strtol()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtol.html) (rather carefully) if you do.  If fields can be blank, you have to work much harder.